# Issues with context path in Spring Boot

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I have a REST API with Spring Boot and Jersey packaged as `jar`. When I run my app (using IntelliJ), I can navigate to:

```
http://localhost:8080/clients
```

and I get all the clients. Now, I have made some changes in `pom.xml` in order to package it as `war` as I need to deploy it in a external Tomcat.

When I package the `war` (named `apirest.war`) and it is deployed in that Tomcat, I navigate to:

```
http://api.mycompany.com/apirest/clients
```

but I get `HTTP 404 Error`. What is happening?

Comment: Have you also added a `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)?

Comment: What's your tomcat server.xml context config look like?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have just added it but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is packaging as a jar really not an option?

I believe Spring Boot is tailored more towards being used with an embedded Tomcat, and have your app packaged as jar.

Then you can comfortably have it run by your OS service/daemon managing tools (e.g. `systemd` on Linux, or even inside a `screen`...)

As additional benefit, by using jar packaging, you remove the dependency on a system Tomcat from your app. You basically only need an OS and a JVM to get going.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IDEA, you can try to add `$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$` in the "Working directory" configuration.

[image]